# how to load a js file and execute it on CEF

Tags: javascript, chromium-embedded

I use CEF(chromium ebedded Framework) load a html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="phantom-limb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it works ok. now, I modify the page as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and after cef loaded it, I use cef's ExecuteJavaScript method to execute the same phantom-limb.js, but nothing appear.

how can I load the js file and execute, or, the js file has some limit?

thx:)

Comment: Two questions: how you determine that the page is loaded? What do you pass to `ExecuteJavaScript`?

Comment: 1) can view the source. 2)mf.ExecuteJavaScript(sl.Text, mf.url, 0);(delphi)

Comment: I meant, what's inside sl.Text

Comment: (delphi):
sl := tStringList.create;
sl.LoadFromFile('phantom-limb.js');
mf.ExecuteJavaScript(sl.Text, mf.url, 0);
sl.Free;

Comment: Is it possible that the code inside the JS file is triggered by the DOM creation/loading? In that case, those event happened before the JS execution

Comment: the JS is at https://github.com/brian-c/phantom-limb I don't know much about javascript, can u help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the end of the [source code](https://github.com/brian-c/phantom-limb/blob/master/phantom-limb.js) of you JS file, the `startOnLoad` config parameter is set to `true` by default.

In this way a listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` is added, which is never called because your page is already loaded.

So, you just have to append the line `start();` to your source code, then call your `ExecuteJavaScript` and it will work even after the page is loaded.