# ReferenceError: $ is not defined [jQuery] [CEF]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, chromium-embedded

I'm learning both HTML and JavaScript and I am getting this error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I was already getting this error and was told to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the `<head>`, which I did.
I was also told to make sure all jQuery javascript code is being run inside a code block such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

I did so. However, I'm still getting the same error.

[image]

What's the reason, then? Am I using a wrong version? What's wrong? Here's the full code:

html.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <body>
        <div class="org-bar">
            <h1 style="font-size:20px;">Criar Organização</h2>
            <form id="orgCreation" action="welcome.php" method="post"></form>>
                <label for="orgName"></label>
                <input class="textInput" type="text" id="orgName" name="orgName" placeholder="Nome da Organização [5-20]" minlength="5" maxlength="20">
                <label for="orgAbb"></label>
                <input class="textInput" type="text" id="orgAbb" name="orgAbb" placeholder="Abreviatura da Organização [3-4]" minlength="3" maxlength="4">
                <input class="button" type="button" id="orgButton" value="Criar">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
            <script src="orgcreation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see I first call jQuery on the head and only on the bottom of the body do I call the javascript file.
orgcreation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("orgButton").click(function(){
        mp.trigger('orgCreation', $('#orgName').val(), $('#orgAbb').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Aint you missing `#` in `$("orgButton")` ?

Comment: I added it, but I'm still getting the same error.
`
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orgButton").click(function(){
        mp.trigger('orgCreation', $('#orgName').val(), $('#orgAbb').val());
    });
});
`

Comment: Also what is mp?

Comment: It looks like you're testing this with one of the Redmond Middle School Science Project browsers (IE or legacy Edge).  Test it with Chrome, Firefox, or new Edge, and use devtools. You may get more useful troubleshooting data.

Comment: are you sure jquery is loading? Check your dev tools. If you are not on a page secured with `https` - it will get blocked. Try changing your script src to `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Does the machine on which you are loading the HTML in the browser have a connection to the internet? jquery include may be failing to load?

Comment: I am using CEF. Yes, I do have internet connection. I am not using this in a browser, it's in a game that supports CEF. The html get shown inside the game.

Comment: sidenote, them `<meta` and `<link` go in `<head>` not outside it, you should also define content type as utf-8 or them `çã`'s will most likely become `��`

Comment: Make sure it supports loading external resources (scripts / css). Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/29191363/1260204

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If `$ is not defined` then adding `$(document).ready` and adding `$("#..` is a bit pointless...

Comment: Thanks, @LawrenceCherone. I will do that

Comment: If with files you mean HTML, the page shows up in the game perfectly once I press the button to open it.

Comment: Your code works fine. Check https://plnkr.co/edit/jlxqWjnl9QvO6FU0?preview ..... can you post the console output and view page source output

Comment: You are mentioning a game. Does you game have internet access?

Comment: Hi. @AlaksandarJesusGene. There's no console output. It's just that error. What should I head for the console.log? And I can't view page source as it's in a CEF in a game. It loads the page, but I'm not in a browser

Comment: Yes, @Yeronimo. It's RAGE:MP, a multiplayer mod of GTA 5. I'm connected to localhost, but I still have internet

Comment: As a security feature you might not be able to load 3rd party libraries. What you can do is download the jquery file(right click on the link or copy paste it as jquery.js in your project folder) and map it instead of ajax.googleapis, .... something like <script src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: Hi @AlaksandarJesusGene. I followed what you said and switched it to this:  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

The name is correct and it's in the same folder, however it still crashes

Comment: Try this    $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});

Comment: In chrome developer tools, what does the request for jquery look like?